# Sum column 2 of .csv file if column 1 is the same

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file where column 1 is the name of a gene and column 2 is a value associated with that gene. However, some genes have multiple values and I want to sum the values of column 2 if column 1 is the same.

So, if for example I had some file `test.csv` that looked like this:

```
eee,55
ddd,60
eee,5
aaa,70
aaa,50
ddd,100
fff,30
```

I would like it to return:

```
eee,60
ddd,160
aaa,120
fff,30
```

I tried using

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
        NR != 1 { y[$1] += $2; $2 = y[$1]; x[$1] = $0; }
        END { for (i in x) { print x[i]; } }'
```

But the output I am getting is

```
eee,5
fff,30
aaa,120
ddd,160
```

Why is it working for every value except the eee's?

Comment: I guess I was. I didn't realize that's what that meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're skipping a non-existent CSV header: `NR != 1`. Without it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
        { y[$1] += $2; $2 = y[$1]; x[$1] = $0; }
        END { for (i in x) { print x[i]; } }' foo
aaa,120
eee,60
ddd,160
fff,30
```

Comment: is there some way to preserve the order of column 1?

Comment: Disregard that comment, I reordered it using grep.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have done with below `awk`.

```
awk -F, '{y[$1]+=$2}END{for (x in y) print x","y[x]}' in.txt
```